# Why is a variable resistor (R101) used in this circuit?

Tags: voltage-divider, logic-gates, comparator

This is from a brake system plausibility device for a Formula Student race car.

I'm confused why a variable resistor is used in this case and why couldn't there be a regular resistor instead like the one connected to the inverting input of the comparator.

This is a circuit such that when the brakes and throttle are pressed at the same time its shuts off the engine.

[image]

Comment: Probably to calibrate sensor deviations.

Comment: I really hope it does not shut down the engine. Simultaneous brake and accelerator application are not some catastrophic events. They are common in certain kinds of race driving with automatic transmission cars, and cars with steering-wheel actuated gear shifting without need for clutch pedal application. Same goes for electric cars. There’s no need for the engine to produce forward torque when the brake is applied, obviously. An ICE should not be idled when brake is applied. The driver who will apply both knows what they are doing. Rally driving with automatics is a two-foot affair.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica : il all depends on the motors and the brakes : in a previous company, we had a robot with parking brakes (ie brakes on when the robot is unpowered or immobile) which need to be powered to release the breaking. Due to a wire coming loose, the breaks were once active while driving : we nearly stalled the motors, which resulted in a strong overheating of the motors to the point of burning away some isolation of the windings, destroying the motors. So braking while accelerating CAN be a catastrophic failure, depending on the design

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume they used variable resistors to be able to tune the thresholds.
With this potentiometer the threshold value on the positiv pin of the comparator can be set for the needed value without soldering in different resistors.
Maybe it is/was necessary to change the amount of force on the brake at which the brake is considered to be "on".